# I have a 404 error on my GitHub public profile, can you help me?

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-for-windows

I am having a problem with my profile, created in November 2023: I am studying software development and today my project colleagues have noticed me that they could not see our past repositories (error 404 for all of them), I see everything on my profile, it is a public profile (I have no changed it, I have checked it). If they try to reach me on GitHub is a 404 page what appears instead of my profile but I can see everything. Also my public pages show a 404 error if you click the link.
The only thing I have done yesterday is to load 3 team work from repositories created by my colleagues to be able to show also on my profile... Is this maybe the reason? I have opened a discussion / question on GitHub community but I have no response.

I am trying to solve but I have no idea! I have checked settings, last activity (everything is mine, not from a foreign IP)... Any idea?

I have tried to change public/ private settings (current profile: public), I have checked last logs, activities, log out and log in session.